# Can someone explain me how this sorting algo is working, and what is the name of this algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I have created a sorting function. Can I know the name of this algorithm? Is this bubble sort?

I am new in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int *, int);

int main(void) {
    int arrayNum[] = {1, 12, 8, 4, 90, 11, 76};
    int len = sizeof(arrayNum) / sizeof(arrayNum[0]);
    sort(arrayNum, len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", arrayNum[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void sort(int *array, int length) {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is known as an [exchange sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort). It's a mixture of bubble sort, and selection sort, with none of the benefits of either.

Comment: This isn't even a true exchange sort. In the given code, as `i` rises the range 0..i covered by the inner `j` loop, which always starts at 0, is completely worthless, yet done anyway. A normal exchange sort runs the inner loop ranged on `j=i+1; j<length`

Comment: The calculation of the length is excellent.

Comment: @Neil It is the standard idiom as far as I can tell. Do I miss something? (`size_t` might be better, but that is strictly speaking not part of the calculation....)

Comment: @Neil or `size_t len = sizeof arrayNum / sizeof arrayNum[0];`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've found that people who are new at C often think, "I have to make `x` length array," instead of, "what is the length of the static data previously entered?" which is more in keeping with C's model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). It doesn't compare *adjacent* elements nor implements any check to stop traversing if the array becomes sorted.

It's similar to [exchange sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort), which could be implemented like the following (note the differences, though):

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // At every step, searches the minimum of the remaining elements     
    for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
        //       ^^^^^                          It doesn't touch the already sorted
        if ( array[j] < array[i] ) {
            //    ^^^        ^^^                To sort the array in ascending order
            /* swap array[j] and array[i] */
        }
    }
}
```

I'd argue that the posted algorithm is much more similar to [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). See how it transforms the array:

```
Starting point
1, 12, 8, 4, 90, 11, 76

Swaps 1 with 12 and then 12 with 90.
90,   1, 8, 4, 12, 11, 76

Swaps 90 with 1.
1, 90,   8, 4, 12, 11, 76

Swaps 90 and 8. In other words, it "inserts" 8 in an already sorted partition.
1, 8, 90,   4, 12, 11, 76

Inserts 4 (it first swaps 8 and 4, then 90 and 8).
1, 4, 8, 90,   12, 11, 76

Inserts 12 (swaps 90 and 12).
1, 4, 8, 12, 90,   11, 76

Inserts 11 (swaps 12 and 11, then 90 and 11).
1, 4, 8, 11, 12, 90,   76

Inserts 76 (swaps 90 and 76), then ends.
1, 4, 8, 11, 12, 76, 90
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has a name, but it's described in this paper: ["Is this the simplest (and most surprising) sorting algorithm ever?"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.01111) Stanley P. Y. Fung